# C# and SQL Server stored procedure thread safety

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, c#-3.0

I am working on a website that sells material (sheet wood for example). An end user can enter the dimensions they require and via an Ajax call and corresponding web service the dimensions are passed into a stored procedure which calculates the cost of the piece of wood the user wants.

The website has been running for a couple of years now and just every so often a user managed to get a price that is incorrect - even stranger is that the price they get is the price of a piece of wood that another user has got a price on at the same time (give or take a few milliseconds) - different material, different dimensions, but somehow the wrong price is returned to the wrong user.

I've tried all sorts to get to the bottom of this but cannot figure it out. Via logging within the database I can see that even when a user gets the wrong price, the values passed into the stored procedure were correct. This would lead me to believe that when the value is returned from the stored procedure somehow the wrong value is returned to the user. How is this even possible? Could it be something to do with the thread safety of the caller?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Dotdev

Comment: Can you post the sproc?

Comment: One thing to mention is that I considered putting a lock around the main method .Net call to the database, but it just seems like a performance overhead that would adversely affect the site.

Comment: Jacob I’ll post it shortly, but out of interest why do you ask? Is it possible that sql itself is almost non thread safe?

Comment: I very much doubt this is a SQL issue. Much more likely there is something in the middle-tier that mixes up the values.

Comment: I would lean towards the same conclusion deroby, but short of putting a lock in place I can think of another solution. Is there anything less aggressive than a lock that could be used?

Comment: Do you use the NOLOCK hint? What you are describing sounds very much like some of nasty hidden benefits of that particular query hint.

Comment: are you using any ##temp tables?